# How to create speech bubbles for text in Flutter? (WhatsApp ui)

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I'm trying to learn Flutter by making a clone of WhatsApp. I've run into a problem with displaying messages in a speech bubble format like in WhatsApp.

I've tried to look at Google's tutorials, but their tutorial for a messenger only uses straight up rows.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can use these https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_superchat

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Maybe not really look like Whatsapp
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Bubble extends StatelessWidget {
  Bubble({this.message, this.time, this.delivered, this.isMe});

  final String message, time;
  final delivered, isMe;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bg = isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.greenAccent.shade100;
    final align = isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.start : CrossAxisAlignment.end;
    final icon = delivered ? Icons.done_all : Icons.done;
    final radius = isMe
        ? BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
          )
        : BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
          );
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: align,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: .5,
                  spreadRadius: 1.0,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.12))
            ],
            color: bg,
            borderRadius: radius,
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 48.0),
                child: Text(message),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(time,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black38,
                          fontSize: 10.0,
                        )),
                    SizedBox(width: 3.0),
                    Icon(
                      icon,
                      size: 12.0,
                      color: Colors.black38,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class BubbleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade50,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: .9,
        title: Text(
          'Putra',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.videocam,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.call,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.more_vert,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Bubble(
              message: 'Hi there, this is a message',
              time: '12:00',
              delivered: true,
              isMe: false,
            ),
            Bubble(
              message: 'Whatsapp like bubble talk',
              time: '12:01',
              delivered: true,
              isMe: false,
            ),
            Bubble(
              message: 'Nice one, Flutter is awesome',
              time: '12:00',
              delivered: true,
              isMe: true,
            ),
            Bubble(
              message: 'I\'ve told you so dude!',
              time: '12:00',
              delivered: true,
              isMe: false,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer ! :)

Comment: I simplified the solution. Just use the widget with single line - https://arkapp.medium.com/chat-bubble-widget-for-flutter-95d3bb82ddd8

Comment: This only really works with short, single line text. Put in long text and it overflows.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this ready made widget:
https://pub.dev/packages/bubble
Easy to implement
Paste this in dependencies section pubspec.yaml:

`bubble: ^1.1.9+1`

And then use it like:

```
    Bubble(
  color: Color.fromRGBO(212, 234, 244, 1.0),
  child: Text('TODAY', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0)),
),
```